# Multiple user session handling in Alexa skill

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

How to mange multiple users playing with your alexa skill at the same time?, I know session can store the game score of one user when he starts playing. But what if one more user plays at the same time. How session can manage it? How can I code is such a way that it can manage multiple user sessions in alexa game skill?

*eg: userA, userB playing this game skill at the same time from two alexa devices. user A got 10 points in score attribute (sessionAttributes.Score = 10) , user B got 20 points (sessionAttributes.Score = 20) in the same score attribute. Now the game crashes for both users when they continue playing!*

How to mange this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it is implemented, but every session has its own id which is completely unique. So in your code, you should store session attributes based of the session id or user id (if you intent to store values for more gameplays).

Comment: How can I store sessions attributes for different users in Alexa skill?

Comment: You need to do it on the server side. In the alexa request find attribute `session.sessionId` and this you can use as key or whatever in your database, where you put `session.attributes`

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use database here. I want to store these session variables for a user game session and reuse it for another user. Only issue was that, it overlaps!

Comment: oki, Than store it in associative array like `$Array[session.sessionId] = session.attributes`